# How do I put two selects in a query and add/change a column too?

Tags: sql

How do you put two selects in a query, and add/change a column too?
An example of what I'm trying to do is hopefully explained below.

```
Ex: Table [TESTS]
TESTID   TEST
   1     Login
   2     Password
   3     Create Account
   4     Edit Account
   5     Close Account

Would like to end up with a query result:
TestType   TESTID     TEST
  Init        1       Login
  Init        2       Pasword
  Func        3       Create Account
  Func        4       Edit Account
  Func        5       Close Account

/* This doesn't work: */
select 'Init' as [TestType], TESTID, TEST from TESTS where (TESTID >= 1 AND TESTID <= 2)
select 'Func' as [TestType], TESTID, TEST from TESTS where (TESTID >= 3 AND TESTID <= 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using case :

```
select 
   CASE WHEN (TESTID = 1 OR TESTID = 2) THEN 'Init' ELSE 'Func' END TestType
 , TESTID
 , TEST 
 from 
   TESTS
```